# how a task is displayed in the timeline

Tags: tasks, task-list, timeline

Is it possible to show a task that has a start and end date as a single date callout based only on one of the dates? I have a lot of tasks with soft start dates and hard due dates. I want to display only the due date for these tasks in the timeline, but I still want to list the start date in the list.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way (ie no programming or advanced setup) would be to add a zero duration task to follow each of your current tasks. Add these to the timeline and as the dates of your main tasks move, so the points on the timeline move.

The downside of this is that you would have to setup each of the tasks separately, not ideal if you have lots of tasks